# Integrate existing MVC view into Umbraco

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

I have created an Umbraco site using the latest version (6.1.6) as an MVC site. Now I have an existing website which retrieves a list of users. I would like to integrate these pages into Umbraco under a custom section. In previous versions of Umbraco (4.7), I used to create user controls in .NET to perform my non-Umbraco db tasks and then link them up in Umbraco by dropping the DLL and the user control in.

How do I do this with the MVC site? I did a bit of reading up on SurfaceController and RenderMVCController but am confused as I really don't want to use any Umbraco related controllers. I would just like to integrate the existing views/controllers into the Umbraco site like I used to do with .NET user controls

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: I want to achieve the same functionality as you do. Did you ever figure out the way to do it? I was able to integrate existing MVC application as a subdirectory to the umbraco site in IIS. But I am not yet sure how to render/embed existing views inside the Umbraco site as you do with asp.net web forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use webforms controls like you did before. Umbraco lets you mix Web Forms and MVC, however it's based on the page. As far as I'm aware, you can't mix MVC and Web Forms functionality into a single page, but you can have both Web Forms and MVC pages in your application.

If you are able to get by with it, you can create a new page using a Master Page template (non-MVC) and use your usercontrol macros there.